# Unable to open display to specific user in Red Hat 6.4

Tags: xorg, environment-variables, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install Oracle database 11g in my Red Hat 6.4 and the installer aborts with a warning followed by an error message:

Warning "`>>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set. Failed <<<`"

Error mesage: "`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.INternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the valeu of the DISPLAY variable`"

I checked the DISPLAY variable and its value is ":0.0". I run /usr/bin/xdpyinfo and it does not work. It returns:

```
No protocol specified
xdpyinfo: unable to open display ":0.0".
```

This problem occurs only with 'oracle' user.

I am in a Virtual Box machine.

Comment: This question was posted originally in stackoverflow and dba.exchange. I did not remove it because I am not be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem modifying the way as I logged in with oracle user.

I was typing: `su oracle`

And then I did: `su - oracle`

and it worked.

I was loading the root instead of oracle environment variables.

I hope that it helps someone else.